# Fingerprint comparison

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, fingerprint

I'm working currently on a authentication project using a Raspberry Pi 3 a Fingerprint Scanner - TTL (GT-511C3) and python as a programming language.
I managed to connect the scanner to the pi and make it work.

Since i'm still a beginner i don't know how i should compare two fingerprints to know if they're identical. Currently i'm saving the prints as png files and earlier i was saving them as pickle files.

My question now is : what is the best way to compare two fingerprints and what is the percentage that i should work with in my comparison to consider two fingerprints identical and how i could achieve that in python.

**NOTE :** I'm going to create a database to store the fingerprints of the users that they're allowed to enter the room for example. And everytime a fingerprint was taken it should go to the database and search if there is a similar one.

Thank you in advance.

**Here is two png files of a fingerprint of the same person taken twice :**

[image] [image]

Comment: This reads broad and although i never did touch this topic, it's so old, that your first step should be a [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=fingerprint+matching&btnG=) for academic papers (i'm assuming this research-area is somewhat open and not only goverment-like without disclosure). (edit: i linked a search for matching; keep in mind that matching might not be necessarily the same as authentication; probably different penalties for false positives)

Comment: You'll probably need a CNN, aka Convolutional Neural Network.

Comment: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/how-to-use-raspberry-pi-fingerprint-sensor-authentication/

Not that I havn't used the library mentioned in the article, I don't know if it's good enough for a real (production) auth system.

Comment: @jbch : does the library works too with the Scanner i'm working with ? ( TTL (GT-511C3) )

Comment: Have the same question of yours, need to try solutions like https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/nist-biometric-image-software-nbis NIST software... or openCV

Comment: More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205489/opencv-fingerprint-image-and-compare-against-database