# Is there a clever way to "double up" bits in an integer?

Tags: c++, math, binary

Say I have the binary number `0b00110101`.

Is there a set of trivial arithmetic operations that will produce `0b0000111100110011`, where every bit of the first word is repeated twice?

Does such a trivial function exist to repeat bits 3, 4, or N times?

Comment: Short of a lookup table, I think the answer is: no.  Whether implicitly or explicitly, you need to unpack the bits in the input word.

Comment: @Nate It's just one way to write a binary number and mark it as such (similar to people usually using `0x0000` for hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: @Nate: that's a binary literal, which I believe c++ supports.

Comment: It's pretty easy using bit shifting and or, but that requires a loop.

Comment: @Mario oh ok thanks I'm not familiar with that my bad.

Comment: @Eric: Look up table (8 bit -> 16 bit) probably best all round solution. If working on low level code / hardware, I've seen people hardwire I/O ports out to in to achieve this kind of thing.

Comment: What you're after is bit wise interleaving. In this particular case, you want to interleave a byte into itself, which will produce the result you want. Just mentioning this since there are question on SO already on how to interleave bits.

Comment: Some architectures (including Intel's x86 in a few months) have instructions that make it almost trivial.

Comment: Write your program in [INTERCAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL) and use the INTERLEAVE operator.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: so, like always, write a trivial implementation behind a function; then optimize when you need and can (LUTs/bitwise/builtin).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at this document:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140629081102/http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN

It describes interleaving two 16-bit numbers, and it's fairly trivial to extend it to 32-bit numbers (this creating a 64-bit number).  You just continue the pattern for one extra cycle.  Like this:

```
static const unsigned long long B[] = {
    0x5555555555555555,
    0x3333333333333333,
    0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F,
    0x00FF00FF00FF00FF,
    0x0000FFFF0000FFFF
};
static const unsigned int S[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};

unsigned long long x; // x must initially fit inside 32 bits
unsigned long long z; // z gets the result of x interleaved with itself

x = (x | (x << S[4])) & B[4];
x = (x | (x << S[3])) & B[3];
x = (x | (x << S[2])) & B[2];
x = (x | (x << S[1])) & B[1];
x = (x | (x << S[0])) & B[0];

z = x | (x << 1);
```

Comment: I forgot to answer the second part of your question, regarding triplicate etc...  I believe the same thing applies but using different magic numbers in `B`.  There's an existing question about 3-value Morton Numbers on SO that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024754/how-to-compute-a-3d-morton-number-interleave-the-bits-of-3-ints

Comment: This was the kind of solution I suspected existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would make a table - it's PROBABLY the quickest way.

You could of course do this:

```
 int doublebits(int x)
 {
     int y = 0;
     int bit = 0;
     while(x)
     {
        if (x & 1)
            y |= 3 << bit;
        bit += 2;
        x >>= 1;
     }
     return y;
 }
```

For an 8-bit number, you'll do at most 8 shifts down, and 8 shifts to the right to make the new number.

Comment: I don't think you need to use an if inside the loop, it should be possible with just logical shifts and or, at least it would in Assembler.

Comment: I wrote it so that's reasonably readable. If you want speed, use that function to generate a table. [I don't expect a modern compiler, at least gcc and MS to generate a branch anyways].

Comment: `x >> 1` is a dangling statement. What did you mean for it to do?

Comment: Fixed.. Thanks for spotting [and the missing space!]

Comment: Readable and clever don't need to go together. I agree the table solution is faster, but seriously ugly.  Something done with bit manipulation only would appeal to the Assembler geeks.

Comment: I was trying to think of if there was some clever way to multiply the number, and it wouldn't surprise me if there is a way somewhere on the interweb. But usually when I need something like this, I either can make a table, or it's not so speed critical that you need cleverness. SOme sort of multiplication should do the trick, but I couldn't think of it for the moment.

Comment: How does this work? Sorry I'm bad when it comes to bits but can you please explain so I can understand?? I know the if statement means "if `x` is odd" but the rest I do not get. :)

Comment: @templateboy - remember that `3` decimal is `11` binary. Now, assume `bit` contains the offset of the current double-bits, so if `x` is odd, then `y = y | (0b11 << bit)`. For each new bit of `x`, increase the offset by 2, shift `x` by 1 position to the right, discarding the last lsb, and repeat the calculation until the last non-zero bit of `x`. HTH.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yep, I located and adapted some clever code from the web.  It's basically multiplication, but combined with a series of masks.  See the code in my answer =)

Comment: @ysap Thanks got it. One more question: why are we using the number 3? Whats so special about it?

Comment: 3 is the same as 11 in binary - if there is a 1 in the input binary, we want 11 in the output binary. Same if you wanted 3 bits, you'd use 7, if you want four bits, you'd use 15, etc [and of course `bits += 3` and `bits += 4` respectively.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - "I wrote it so that's reasonably readable."
I don't think adding a redundant check improves readability - it simply makes the program longer. IMO it'd be a bit simpler and clearer without the if.

Comment: @Desty: That depends on the experience of the reader. For someone familiar with binary encoding and decoding, sure. For the average programmer, it's (a little) easier to get this way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this time I believe to have found the correct sequence:

http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C12%2C15%2C48&sort=&language=&go=Search

One way they suggest producing it is recursively:

a(2n) = 4a(n), a(2n+1) = 4a(n) + 3.

which is anything but trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious), it seems that the techniques either require LUTs or loops. So, I think the most elegant way will be to use the "Obvious way" (linked) while setting `y = x` prior to the calculation.

```
unsigned short x;   // Interleave bits of x and y, so that all of the
unsigned short y;   // bits of x are in the even positions and y in the odd;
unsigned int z = 0; // z gets the resulting Morton Number.

x = INPUT_PATTERN;
y = x;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT; i++) // unroll for more speed...
{
  z |= (x & 1U << i) << i | (y & 1U << i) << (i + 1);
}
```

Yes, I am aware it is not necessarily the "clever" solution that the OP asks for, but the other answers so far include loops/recursion as well, so why not give it a try...